# Why is there a difference between model.evaluate and model.predict results?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, confusion-matrix

I have created a model based off of VGG-16 using transfer learning with a cats and dogs dataset. I've trained the model and evaluated it with around 91% accuracy. When using model.predict my and putting it into a confusion matrix the results are 50/50.

Heres the code for the data generators

```
trdata = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,
    rotation_range=5,
    zoom_range=(0.95, 0.95),
    horizontal_flip=True,
    vertical_flip=True)
​
traindata = trdata.flow_from_directory(
    directory='/tmp/cats-v-dogs/training/', 
    target_size=(224,224),
    batch_size=128,
    shuffle=True,
    class_mode='categorical')
​
vldata = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1.0 / 255.)
valdata = vldata.flow_from_directory(
    directory='/tmp/cats-v-dogs/validation/', 
    target_size=(224,224),
    shuffle=True,
    class_mode='categorical')
​
testdata = vldata.flow_from_directory(
    directory='/tmp/cats-v-dogs/testing/', 
    target_size=(224,224),
    shuffle=True,
    class_mode='categorical')

Found 19998 images belonging to 2 classes.
Found 2500 images belonging to 2 classes.
Found 2500 images belonging to 2 classes.
```

Heres what I added to the pretrained model

```
trdata = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,
    rotation_range=5,
    zoom_range=(0.95, 0.95),
    horizontal_flip=True,
    vertical_flip=True)
​
traindata = trdata.flow_from_directory(
    directory='/tmp/cats-v-dogs/training/', 
    target_size=(224,224),
    batch_size=128,
    shuffle=True,
    class_mode='categorical')
​
vldata = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1.0 / 255.)
valdata = vldata.flow_from_directory(
    directory='/tmp/cats-v-dogs/validation/', 
    target_size=(224,224),
    shuffle=True,
    class_mode='categorical')
​
testdata = vldata.flow_from_directory(
    directory='/tmp/cats-v-dogs/testing/', 
    target_size=(224,224),
    shuffle=True,
    class_mode='categorical')
```

Compiled using SGD and binary_accuracy

```
from tensorflow.keras import optimizers
model_final.compile(loss = "binary_crossentropy", optimizer=optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.001, momentum=0.9, decay=0.0005), metrics=["binary_accuracy"])
model_final.summary()
```

The model was trained for about 10 epochs and here is the evaluation:

```
test_loss, test_acc= model_final.evaluate(testdata)
print(test_loss)
print(test_acc)

79/79 [==============================] - 10s 129ms/step - loss: 0.2132 - binary_accuracy: 0.9192
0.21318960189819336
0.9192000031471252
```

And here the results using model.predict

```
#Confution Matrix and Classification Report
Y_pred = model_final.predict(testdata, 2500)
y_pred = np.argmax(Y_pred, axis=1)
print('Confusion Matrix')
print(confusion_matrix(testdata.classes, y_pred))
print('Classification Report')
target_names = ['Cats', 'Dogs']
print(classification_report(testdata.classes, y_pred, target_names=target_names))
```

```
Confusion Matrix
[[665 585]
 [685 565]]
Classification Report
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

        Cats       0.49      0.53      0.51      1250
        Dogs       0.49      0.45      0.47      1250

    accuracy                           0.49      2500
   macro avg       0.49      0.49      0.49      2500
weighted avg       0.49      0.49      0.49      2500
```

Why is the accuracy so low on the confusion matrix, I don't understand I thought the model would perform much better given that the evaluation's accuracy was in the 90's. Throughout training the accuracy and validation accuracy was never below 0.8 either. Any ideas why these results are like this or am is there an error in the prediction part?

Comment: This is a common misconception, generator.classes does not give you the class labels in the same order as you predicted them.

Comment: Can you elaborate? I can't make sense of that.

Comment: When using a generator, you cannot use generator.classes to give you the ground truth, that is why the predictions do not match. you need to iterate on the generator together with making predictions.

Comment: I changed the class_mode in the data generators to binary and now when learning the accuracy and validation accuracy is similarly around 0.5 each epoch. How could I solve this?